# Ubuntu 16 stuck on installation

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, system-installation

I downloaded the newest Ubuntu version from their website and then used the universal USB installer to put it on a USB. I then put the USB in my computer and restarted.

It then asked me if I wanted to just try Ubuntu or install it, to which I pressed "install".

Problem is that now it seems to be stuck (see image), and I'm not sure what's wrong.

It's been like this for half an hour.

How do I proceed?

[image: boot image]

Comment: I downloaded version 16.04.3

Comment: What's happening if you "Just Try Ubuntu" as a live disk? If that's boot up you can install it afterwards. Otherwise try another version of Ubuntu.

Comment: This is probably casued by buggy or out of date BIOS. Please add your systems exact model number and if you can the BIOS version.